The formula field on page header doesn't show on every page in Crystal report
I have a sub report and I need to store the first row data and place it on header. I create the formula to store the data. However it didn't show on every page. Would someone told me how to fix it.
I tried use the global and shared variable and still doesn't work
There are my formula:
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global StringVar week;
  if RecordNumber = 1 then
 week:={Report_SubReport;1.Date};

second formula:
if RecordNumber = 1 then
   Shared StringVar week:= {Report_SubReport;1.Date}
else
    Shared StringVar week;


Subreports don't show their own Page Header (PH) section because they are hosted in a page belonging to the main report.
As a way around this issue, create a dummy group level 1 in the subreport. It can use a formula with a constant value. Place the content in GH1 instead of in PH. And turn on the option to repeat GH on each new page:


I am not familiar with crrystal report and I tried to do it as your instruction but  it didn't show any record.  I f the column has value then return true else return false.  Would you give me more detail information. Thanks for spending time to reply my answer.
